# Why would a SynchronizationEvent point to itself?

Tags: windbg

I'm trying to understand deadlocks/livelocks at a kernel level and exploring different wait-objects. Using [notmyfault](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901) I created a system hang and forced a memory dump. Showing the process for notmyfault I see two threads; one which is attempting to acquire a fast mutex and is awaiting a SynchronizationEvent and the other is awaiting multiple objects - all SynchronizationTimers.

```
THREAD fffffa800895f060  Cid 0f6c.0f5c  Teb: 000007fffffde000 Win32Thread: fffff900c206bc20 WAIT: (WrFastMutex) KernelMode Non-Alertable
    fffff88006ed0198  SynchronizationEvent
```

and

```
THREAD fffffa800895c060  Cid 0f6c.0f20  Teb: 000007fffffdc000 Win32Thread: 0000000000000000 WAIT: (UserRequest) UserMode Alertable
    fffffa80069d8ef0  SynchronizationTimer
    fffffa80093d28c0  SynchronizationTimer
    fffffa800948e060  SynchronizationTimer
```

I check the dispatch header on the first synchronization event:

```
3: kd> dt nt!_DISPATCHER_HEADER fffff88006ed0198
   *SNIP*
   +0x008 WaitListHead     : _LIST_ENTRY [ 0xfffffa80`0895f168 - 0xfffffa80`0895f168 ]
```

and the kwait block on the wait list header.

```
3: kd> dt nt!_KWAIT_BLOCK 0xfffffa80`0895f168
   +0x000 WaitListEntry    : _LIST_ENTRY [ 0xfffff880`06ed01a0 - 0xfffff880`06ed01a0 ]
   +0x010 Thread           : 0xfffffa80`0895f060 _KTHREAD
   +0x018 Object           : 0xfffff880`06ed0198 Void
   +0x020 NextWaitBlock    : 0xfffffa80`0895f168 _KWAIT_BLOCK
    *SNIP*
```

Looking at the waitlist of the other thread seems to make sense to me: The deadlock appears to be caused by each of the kwait_blocks referencing each other in a sort of loop (which I guess is the actual definition of a deadlock).

The problem I'm having is with the dispatcher header and kwait block above. My assumption would have been that the first thread would be waiting on the thread that is looping on itself with the synchronization timers. I'm assuming that I have missed a step or am simply misunderstanding but why does the NextWaitBlock reference itself instead?

**EDIT**:

Additionally I noticed that none of these events/timers indicate that they have been signaled but fffffa800948e060 contains an inserted timer. My understanding is that the causative event would have to be in a signaled state, is this incorrect or is there another wait object that I have overlooked?

Comment: A LIST_ENTRY header references itself to indicate that the list is empty.  KWAIT_BLOCK might be similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The deadlock appears to be caused by each of the kwait_blocks referencing each other in a sort of loop (which I guess is the actual definition of a deadlock).

You misunderstand the usage of the NextWaitBlock field in the KWAIT_BLOCK structure. Let me start from the beginning (which I know you understand based on your above output) just for the sake of clarity:

When a thread goes to sleep waiting for a Dispatcher Object to become signaled, the thread allocates a KWAIT_BLOCK structure and queues the structure to the Object's DISPATCHER_HEADER. This linkage can be seen by your walking of structured related to thread fffffa800895f060. The Event's DISPATCHER_HEADER has the KWAIT_BLOCK queued to it, and from there you can find the waiting thread.

Windows also supports the ability for a thread to wait on multiple Dispatcher Objects at once. When this happens, the thread allocates a KWAIT_BLOCK structure for each Dispatcher Object, queues each structure to the appropriate DISPATCHER_HEADER, and then links the KWAIT_BLOCK structures together through the NextWaitBlock field. The thread then chooses if it wants to wait for ANY of these Objects to become signaled or for ALL of these Objects to become signaled. Thus, the NextWaitBlock field just links together all of the things that this thread is waiting on, not some kind of infinite loop.

> The problem I'm having is with the dispatcher header and kwait block above. My assumption would have been that the first thread would be waiting on the thread that is looping on itself with the synchronization timers.

The thread is waiting for an Event to become signaled. That's all you get in this case, given the Event there is no way to determine which thread in the system is supposed to set it. This makes resolving these more difficult than, say, a deadlock with a KMUTANT Dispatcher Object. KMUTANTs record which thread owns them, so from there you know where to look next.

> I'm assuming that I have missed a step or am simply misunderstanding but why does the NextWaitBlock reference itself instead?

It's just an implementation detail to indicate an empty list, this thread isn't waiting on any other Dispatcher Objects except the event.

Comment: so - to be clear - there is no way to trace the holder of an event from the waiting thread? Hypothetically though, if I find the event that currently holds the object I should see the waiting thread in the wait_block, correct?

Comment: Correct, just given the event you can't know which thread is supposed to set it. You can know which threads are waiting for the event to become set, but you can't know who is supposed to set it.